Admin Table list view disable clicking anywhere in row to toggle checkbox
In J5 the default behaviour of clicking anywhere an Admin list view table row is now to toggle the checkbox in the first column (for batch processing).
In J3 you had to actually click on the checkbox, not even anywhere in the <td>..</td> for the first column.
If you have a, for example, a <details>...</details> element in another column, clicking the summary to drop down the details now also checks the checkbox in the first column. As does clicking a link anywhere in the row - which is not a problem if the link opens in current window but can be a pain if the link opens a new tab.
Is there a way to disable this behaviour for the whole site? You can do it by adding a event.stopPropagation(); to the onclick on the details element, but you have to do this everywhere. Is there a joomla option to disable this undesirable behaviour?

First you can try reporting this on the issue tracker. Multiselect script actually excludes some interactive elements like links, buttons and inputs but the list is clearly incomplete. <summary> should be added there too.
